# powershell replace special characters

Tags: xml, powershell, replace, special-characters

I am farely new to powershell but I am trying to replace certain characters within .xml files. Looks like I stumble with the first steps already.

e.g. I'll try to replace:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
```

with

```
<?xml version="2.0"?>
```

Below you'll find the code I wrote so  far:

```
Get-Childitem "C:\Users\jp\Desktop\Test" | ForEach-Object {

        $Content = Get-Content $_.fullname
        $Content = ForEach-Object { $Content -replace "(<?xml version=`"1.0`"?>)","(<?xml version=`"2.0`"?>)" }

        Set-Content $_.fullname $Content -Force

        }
```

The problem is that this is just the start of the strings I have to replace. Is there a way to replace any text within a certain range independent from the characters inside?

I wonder how to replace a complete string no matter what special characters I have inside. 
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Use the Escape method to escape special characters at run time. You don't need to escape the replace pattern:

```
(Get-Content c:\dump\xml) | 
ForEach-Object {$_ -replace [regex]::Escape('<?xml version="1.0"?>'),'<?xml version="2.0"?>'} | 
Set-Content c:\dump\xml
```

Comment: That's cool , that's why I,like this place , people helping and learning at the same time .

Answer (score 0):

Hi there are lots of ways to do regex matches you could simply change your code to the one below.

The \ just escapes the special regex charters so that the match part works.

```
Get-Childitem "c:\dump\xml" | ForEach-Object {

        $Content = Get-Content $_.fullname
        $Content = ForEach-Object { $Content -replace '(<\?xml version="1\.0"\?>)','<?xml version="2.0"?>' }

        Set-Content $_.fullname $Content -Force

        }
```